# Que devuelve ByTagName en los siguientes casos?

Tags: javascript

qué devuelve `getElementByTagName('body')` , según:

> 1) Especificando el indice 0
>       Devuelve  ? con todo el contenido y por ende todos los tags dentro de body o solo el tag body en sí?
>
> 2) Sin especificar el indice? , la misma estructura de lo anterior.
>
> 3)En el caso de especificar el indice [0] y [1] a la misma vez osea:

`getElementByTagName('body')[0][1]` ,

> que sucede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código `getElementByTagName('body')` te devuelve un objeto de tipo HTMLCollection el cuál puedes tratar como un `Array` por lo tanto si usas `getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`te devolverá el primer elemento de la colección en forma de html incluyendo todo el html interno del body. Finalmente, como `getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` no es un array si intentas hacer `getElementsByTagName('body')[0][1]` sólo obtendrás `undefined`.

Comment: y si no especifíco el array?

Comment: Cuando no especificas ningún indice es cuando te regresa el Objeto HTMLCollection algo así `[body] > length: 1; 0: body (todo el html)`

Comment: gracias gerarado